# Char to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a char array and want to convert one of the values from char to qstring:

```
unsigned char inBuffer[64];

....
QString str= QString(*inBuffer[1]);
ui->counter->setText(str);
```

This isn't working (I get a compiler error). Any suggestions?

Comment: Which encoding is your input data in?

Comment: e expression `*inBuffer[1]` doesn't get the second character from the string. It takes the second character from the string, treats it as an address and dereferences that address. You probably mean `inBuffer[1]`, without the asterisk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html

```
QString &   operator+= ( char ch )

QString &   operator= ( char ch )
```

You can use operator+= to append a char, or operator= to assign a char.

But in your code it will call constructor, not operator=. There is no constructor for char, so your code can not compile.

```
QString str;
str = inBuffer[1];
```

QString has a constructor

```
QString ( QChar ch )
```

So u can use following code to do that

```
QString str= QChar(inBuffer[1]);
```

or

```
QString str(QChar(inBuffer[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to do that:

```
QString x="";
QChar y='a';

x+=y;
```

So here you have a QString with the char.

Comment: This seems to be a possible way (haven’t tried) but the other answers look easier to me.

Answer (score 2):

if ur var is: `char * p = "hi there";`

You just `QString myGreet = QString::fromLocal8Bit(p);`

Answer (score 1):

How did you declare **inBuffer**? If you meant **outBuffer**, drop the dereference operator:

```
QString str = outBuffer[1];
```